# Issue present in packaged vertsion of Game but not in Editor

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I'm having a frustrating issue currently with Unreal where players spawn won't spawn the packaged version but will in the editor. I think I've managed to pin the issue down, but I still have no idea why it's occurring. For context, I am working on a multiplayer battle arena game. I have a player handler blueprint that stores relevant metadata/info about a character.

[Handler getting Relevant Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TIFf.png)

When the handler is first created, it's assigned a character name and costume/colour variant index from the game instance.

[Getting the correct character from the data asset table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PIXK.png)

It then checks a character data asset table to see which class/mesh/material it should be set to.

[This is the data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sW7w.png)

The data table references data assets. From my testing this seems to be where the issue lies, that the game can access the data tables in the PIE, but not in the build. Does anyone know why this may be? Is there something I've overlooeked?

Comment: How are you referencing the data table: using a path (e.g. /Game/MyDataTable), a soft reference, or a hard reference?